# Rewrite the same asp.net application again

Tags: asp.net, projects-and-solutions

I have a asp.net application which is written in the traditional method [SqlConnection. SqlAdapter.. ..] in data access layer, I can see that every time we are making a connection and using adapters. Code is written in a very dirty manner. I have been given the task to re write the application in standard/best practice way. 
i have all stored procedure already written, is there any way I can use a tool like which will help me in writing the business layer and data access layer?

Comment: There are tons of tools. But if you're tasked with finding the *best* way, shouldn't you do some binging as part of your assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go for codesmith. As you have all the Stored procedure already written you can either go for the LINQ to SQL feature.

Comment: Yes you can use PLINQO (PLINQO.com) to generate the Linq-to-SQL backend. Than you can use your existing stored procedures with PLINQO and get access to all of it's great features.

Answer (score 1):

For the DAL, you could use Entity Framework 4. The business logic could be wrapped up by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fluentAdo.net](http://fluentado.codeplex.com/). You can use it with all your old stored procedures.

But if you really want to rewrite your app, I suggest you to use NHibernate or Entity Framework. They have pretty same set of fetures.